# Static resources with Richfaces 4.x

Tags: richfaces

I am migrating my Web application with Richfaces from 3.3.3 version to 4.1 but I am having several problems with the static resources (images and CSS, mainly). I know that JSF2 has a mechanism to serve this sort of resources (putting all them under a folder named 'resources'). With respect to this I have two questions:

1. Would it be possible to change this folder to another one?
2. What happen with relative paths in CSS? I have many images linked with the 'background-image' property but Richfaces 4.1 doesn't resolve them correctly. For example, I load my CSS, allocated in /resources/css, on this way:

   < h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="wdCalendar/calendar.css"/>

calendar.css contains this class:

```
.cic {
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   display: inline-block;
   background-image: url(images/calendar/combined.gif);
}
```

Richfaces resolves the url as

```
http://nameApp/servletApp/javax.faces.resource/wdCalendar/images/calendar/combined.gif
```

But I suppose it should be

```
http://nameApp/servletApp/resources/css/wdCalendar/images/calendar/combined.gif
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes you can change it, the `src/main/webapp` folder (assuming that's what it looks like in your project) will become `/your-app` on the server and you can use absolute paths from there
2. That's because the h:outputStylesheet puts the resources in a sort of "abstract" folder (I don't know the specifics but that's what it looks like) and lets it be handled by the servlet, look at the way stylesheet links are outputted. There are several ways out of this

   - Use an absolute path

   `/your-app/resources/css/wdCalendar/images/calendar/combined.gif`

   - or a relative path to get out of the "abstract" folder

   `../resources/css/wdCalendar/images/calendar/combined.gif`

   - or use a relative path that the servlet can handle

   `images/calendar/combined.gif.jsf?ln=css/wdCalendar`
   (note the .jsf which is the default servlet mapping defined in web.xml, it might look different in your app; it should look the same way your stylesheet link looks). Also, it doesn't matter what part of the path is in the `ln` (it can be empty) as long as it's a correct path if you put it together.